# Modifying JSON colums in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have data in the following format in my dataframe

```
>>> Surveyresp['Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q']

1     ['item3', 'item4', 'item2', 'item1']

Name: Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q, dtype: object
```

This snipped of data shows the way user responses are formatted in my data to a specific checkbox question 'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q'. So this means this specific participant has selected item1, item 4, item 2 and item 3 for this question.

This survey will be matched to a JSON answer key file and spit out a numeric number that calculates a score. The problem is that the JSON file stores the answers to these questions in a different format. Taking Warehouse.jud_3_3_q as an example, the correct answers for this question are stored as:

```
{'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q.1': ['item1'], 'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q.2': ['item2'], 'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q.3': ['item3'], 'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q.4': ['item4']}
```

The answers for the question are split apart (as q.1, q.2 etc.) which prevents me from matching the the responses in my dataframe to the JSON answer key, which I have read in as a dictionary. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can reformat this answerkey dictionary using pandas?

My desired output would look something like this to match the CSV responses:

```
{'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']}
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output? That's the best way to get a good answer quickly.

Comment: Done! My desired output would essentially look identical to how the responses are on on my dataframe, so that I would eventually be able to match the two for grading.

Answer (score 0):

You can try combine the `q.1` to `q.4` to list

```py
d = {'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q.1': ['item1'], 'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q.2': ['item2'], 'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q.3': ['item3'], 'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q.4': ['item4']}

answer = pd.DataFrame(d).apply(lambda row: row.tolist(), axis=1).to_frame('Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q')
```

```
print(answer)

   Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q
0  [item1, item2, item3, item4]

print(answer.to_dict(orient='list'))

{'Warehouse.Response.jud_3_3_q': [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']]}
```